# Error whenever I run code that requires aiohttp library

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Whenever I run code which requires aiohttp, I get the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\.atom\async8.py", line 1, in <module>
    from aiohttp import web
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .client import *  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 15, in <module>
    from . import connector as connector_mod
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import hdrs, helpers
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\helpers.py", line 30
    ensure_future = asyncio.async
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Examples of codes I've tried to run from https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/ include:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def main():

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('http://python.org') as response:

            print("Status:", response.status)
            print("Content-type:", response.headers['content-type'])

            html = await response.text()
            print("Body:", html[:15], "...")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

and

```
    from aiohttp import web

async def handle(request):
    name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
    text = "Hello, " + name
    return web.Response(text=text)
    

app = web.Application()
app.add_routes([web.get('/', handle),
                web.get('/{name}', handle)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(app)
```

I've tried several other examples but they all produce the same error. What could be causing this?. I'm using python 3.8.6 and the latest version of aiohttp

Update:
It seems the error is caused by importing aiohttp. I get the error just by typing 'import aiohttp' on cmd.

Comment: Hey, just by searching I found it on the [project issue tracker](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/4005), it seems you are not using the last version of the library after all! Next time if you can also put in the versions along with the question so that people now what were you using!

Comment: You are right. Running 'pip install aiohttp' then 'pip list' shows that the version installed is 2.2.5. However, running 'pip install aiohttp==3.5.4' solves the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that
`pip install aiohttp` installs a version incompatible with my current python version. `pip install aiohttp==3.5.4` solved the issue for me. Thank you @edoput for pointing that out.